# Ajax - dropdown selection works great just the first time

Tags: ajax, dropdown

well I'm stuck with this piece of code that send json data to a php file, the first time works great (post the info on the db and all good) but after the first submitions does take the selected dropdown value and updates the DB with old vale in var = name.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$("#rechazar").click(function(){    
        // Here I create a form called "rechazo" (reject in English) with just two buttons and a dropdown
        var rejectForms= $('<form id="formrechazo" name="formrechazo"><select id="dropdown_rechazo" name="dropdown_rechazo"  style="z-index:10000; width: 250px;" ><option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione un motivo de rechazo</option><option value="Vehicle Year">Año del vehículo</option><option value="Vehicle Model">Tipo de vehículo</option><option value="Vehicle Model">Taxi</option><option value="Age">La edad del Driver es menor a los 21 años</option><option value="Unsuitable Documents">Licencia no admitida</option><option value="Unsuitable Documents">Cedula no admitida</option><option value="Duplicate Record">Registro Duplicado</option></form>');
            rejectForms.dialog({    
            modal: true,
```

//Here after creating the form above I say that whenever the ok button is clicked it should take the selected option, (which works great just the first time) but if I hit cancel or update the information the second time does not take the new selected value just the previous one and the .change event at the end does not shows the alert anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
            buttons: { 
                'OK': function () {     
                 var name =  $( "#dropdown_rechazo" ).find( "option:selected" ).prop("value");   
                 //this ID take it from a form on html with id= #myform var rejectID =  $('#ID').val();
                    debugger; var rejectdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({value: rejectID, value2:name})); //The ajax call - works like a charm- 
                var ajax = $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',   
                 url: "http://localhost/reject.php",
                 //context: this,
                 data : ({jsonObj:rejectdata}),
                //contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                 success: function (result) {
//This is a function after I update the php to load info to some divs 
                siguientes();
                                            },
     error: function(result){
                            var json = (result);
                            alert(json.error);
                            }            
     })  
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    rejectForms.reset;
                },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    rejectForms.reset;
                }
              }
            } 
        )           
        $("#dropdown_rechazo").change(function(){
    var name =  $( "#dropdown_rechazo" ).find( "option:selected" ).prop("value");   //$('#dropdown_rechazo').val();
    alert(name)                             
    })  })
</script>
```

Comment: I named the dropdown ids with different IDs and does not work.

Comment: I know that   `var name =  $( "#dropdown_rechazo" ).prop('value')` can be ` $( "#dropdown_rechazo).val" ` is just that I was trying to make find a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move set a 'div' out from ajax call, like this:

```
<div id="dialogoRechazo" title="Dialog Title"><select id="dropdown_rechazo" name="dropdown_rechazo"  style="z-index:10000; width: 250px;" ><option value="" selected="selected">Seleccione un motivo de rechazo</option><option value="Vehicle Year">Año del vehículo</option><option value="Vehicle Model1">Tipo de vehículo</option><option value="Vehicle Model">Taxi</option><option value="Age">La edad del Driver es menor a los 21 años</option><option value="Unsuitable Documents">Licencia no admitida</option><option value="Unsuitable Documents1">Cedula no admitida</option><option value="Duplicate Record">Registro Duplicado</option></div>
```

and then open the form will make the call executes, I was investigating on the dialog documents and it first I need to instanciate the form, this was running just one because the function was loaded the first time with values loaded the first time

> https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

```
<script>
$("#rechazar").click(function(){    
$( "#dialogoRechazo" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    // Dialog here
    $( "#dialogoRechazo" ).dialog( "open" );
    var rejectForms= $( "#dialogoRechazo" );
        rejectForms.dialog({    
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
            'OK': function () {     
                debugger;   let name =  $( "#dropdown_rechazo" ).find( "option:selected" ).prop("value");   //$('#dropdown_rechazo').val();
                    var rejectID =  $('#ID').val();
                debugger; var rejectdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({value: rejectID, value2: name}));
            var ajax = $.ajax({
```